# Github authentication with DotNetOpenAuth in a MVC 4 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, github, dotnetopenauth

DotNetOpenAuth comes with Facebook, Twitter, Google, Microsoft and Yahoo authorization by default. Where should I start if I want to add Github authorization using OAuth. I don't know where to start from. Tried their documentation but didn't got anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I have wrote a Github client sample and hosted it on... github. I have NOT tested it yet, but it should be a good place to start. https://github.com/cvlad/GithubOAuthClient/blob/master/GithubClient.cs

If I were to guess, I'd start with implementing `DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.OAuthClient` or `OAuth2Client`. It has two methods: `RequestAuthentication` and `VerifyAuthentication`.

After that, I'd register the GithubAuthenticationClient using `Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.RegisterClient`.

If I got stuck, I'd check the source of `DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.WindowsLiveClient` or any other client.

You could also check the implementation for the current providers, which you can find here: https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/tree/master/src/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet/Clients